# Stripe—test cards with insufficient funds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

There are some test credit card numbers, e.g. Visa's `4111 1111 1111 1111`, and when you test with these cards, it is always a successful transaction.

How do I test a declined transaction? E.g. if the card is valid but doesn't have enough money for the transaction?

Comment: are you trying to subscribe to failed payment webhooks? Theres no failed cards i believe but you can send yourself failed payment webhooks, you just need to create them.

Comment: I have this problem too, and I don't want to see the webhook event. I want to see a failed Charge object itself, from the initial conversation with Stripe

Comment: Not subscriptions, just a one-time charge. If I can only test successful cards, how will I know what the user will see if they have no money on their valid card?

Comment: Have you checked the entire list of [test numbers in the official documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards)?

Comment: Props to mu - it says down at the bottom "4000000000000002 Charge is declined with a card_declined code."

Comment: oh _snap_, thanks @muistooshort and Phlip, seriously I checked the documentation all the way down to the paragraph above the one I needed! At that point I was thinking "hmm none of these is what I'm looking for"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the card number `4000 0000 0000 0002` or token "tok_chargeDeclined" to get a declined test charge:
https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards

Answer (score 45):

You have two scenarios when a charge can fail:

- Charge directly a customer.
- Attach a card to a customer and then try to charge that customer.

[Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) provides two test cards for those situations:

- `4000 0000 0000 0002` "Charge is declined with a card_declined code."
- `4000 0000 0000 0341` "Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail."

Comment: Nice one. Very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As @Muistooshort and @phlip mention in the comments, the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) give a list of test cards that will return various error messages.

Common errors would be:

`4000 0000 0000 0002` Card declined (e.g. insufficient funds)

`4000 0000 0000 0069` Card expired

`4000 0000 0000 0127` Incorrect CVC

Card dates can be anything in the future (for valid dates) or in the past to test invalid dates.

Answer (score 1):

`4000000000009995` this card number return insufficient funds when I attach it to a customer. I hope it help someone.